# How to hide rows based off of text in another cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to hide rows depending on a different cell. For example, if that cell is "No", I want to automatically hide the following 3 rows since they will no longer pertain. (B14=No, hide rows 14-16). Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    function onEdit(e){

  if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B14' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)'){
    if(e.value=='No') {
    } e.range.getSheet().hideRows(15,16,17);
   
   if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B19' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)'){
     if(e.value=='No') {
     } e.range.getSheet().hideRows(20,21,22);
      
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B24' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)'){
    if(e.value=='No') {
    } e.range.getSheet().hideRows(25,26,27);
   
   if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B29' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)'){
     if(e.value=='No') {
     } e.range.getSheet().hideRows(30,31);
       
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B37' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)'){
    if(e.value=='No') {
    } e.range.getSheet().hideRows(38,39);
   
   if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B41' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)'){
     if(e.value=='No') {
     } e.range.getSheet().hideRows(42,43);
      
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B45' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)'){
    if(e.value=='No') {
    } e.range.getSheet().hideRow(46);
   
   if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B48' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)'){
     if(e.value=='No') {
     } e.range.getSheet().hideRow(49); 
   }
  }
   }
```

Comment: What is the problem with the script? See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function onMyEdit(e){
   //e.source.toast('Entry');
   //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
   const sh=e.range.getSheet();
   const rA=[14,19,24,29,37,41,45,48];//active rows
   const rObj={14:{row:15,num:3},19:{row:20,num:3},24:{row:25,num:3},29:{row:30,num:2},37:{row:38,num:2},41:{row:42,num:2},45:{row:46,num:1},49:{row:49,num:1}};//hideRow Data
   //console.log(JSON.stringify(rObj));
   const idx=rA.indexOf(e.range.rowStart);
   if(sh.getName()=='PST Referral Template (Sheet)' && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.value=="No" && idx>-1) {
     //e.source.toast('conditional');
     sh.hideRows(rObj[rA[idx]].row,rObj[rA[idx]].num);  
   }
}
```

Comment: This script was accepted but the rows are still not hidden

Comment: It worked for me